# Using bash command on a variable that will be used as reference for an array

Tags: bash

Short and direct, basically I want to use the value of `$command` on a variable, instead using it inside the while loop as a command itself. So:

This Works, but I think it's ugly:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
lsof=`which lsof`
whoami=`whoami`

while true ; do
    execution_array=($(${lsof} -iTCP -P 2> /dev/null | grep ':' | grep ${whoami} | awk '{print $9}'  | cut -f2 -d'>' | sort  | uniq ))
    for i in ${execution_array[*]}; do
        echo $i
    done
    sleep 1
done
unset IFS
```

This doesn't work ( no output happens ), but i think is less ugly:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
lsof=`which lsof`
whoami=`whoami`
command="${lsof} -iTCP -P 2> /dev/null | grep ':' | grep ${whoami} | awk '{print $9}'  | cut -f2 -d'>' | sort  | uniq"
while true ; do
    execution_array=($(command))
    for i in ${execution_array[*]}; do
        echo $i
    done
    sleep 1
done
unset IFS
```

Comment: Scripting often looks ugly but storing a command in a variable is not considered good practice, the former is definitely the better solution.

Comment: you are missing a `$` sign in front of `command` (which is an existing command in Bash by the way) `execution_array=($($command))`

Comment: @ShellFish would be better using the ugly way? Storing it on a function would be a better idea?

Comment: @damienfrancois i think i allready tested it aswell =(, doesn't work

Comment: @Thales Yes don't store a command in a variable, it's not a good idea. You should enjoy scripting for being ugly and cryptic, I know I do. - Maybe creating a shell function would not be a bad idea, try it out.

Comment: @ShellFish Worked :) posting it as solution

Comment: You **cannot** store a command in a string in anything like a reliable way. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

lsof=$(which lsof)

list_connections() {
    ${lsof} -iTCP -P 2> /dev/null | grep ':' | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $9}'  | cut -f2 -d'>' | sort  | uniq
}
while true ; do
    execution_array=($(list_connections))
    for i in ${execution_array[*]}; do
        echo $i
    done
    sleep 1
done
unset IFS
```

Comment: You should execute `lsof=$(which lsof)` and `whoami=$(whoami)` before calling the function. Now they will be executed every single time the loop repeats. Instead, execute them before the while and pass them as parameters to the function.

Comment: As indicated in a comment on the post `command` is a bad name as it is already a shell built-in with a very useful purpose.

Comment: Both sugestions added into the solution